# Does the Elizabeth leader bonus in Civ5 also apply to embarked units?

Tags: civilization-5

In Civ5, Elizabeth gets the bonus:

> +2 movement for all naval units

Does this also apply to embarked (land-)units?

Note: The manual is a *bit* more precise:

> **Unique Trait** Sun Never Sets: +2 MPs
>   for all ocean-going naval units.

So this would mean you get this only after you have discovered the tech that lets you enter ocean tiles. Still does not specify if it applies to embarked units also?

Comment: I believe it does, but I'm not in a position to be able to confirm it.

Comment: I remember someone saying embarked units are still categorised as 'land units', so they do not receive the bonuses. Have not verified yet.

Comment: Perhaps, but they benefit from the great lighthouse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can confirm that embarked land units do get an extra two movements under Elizabeth's special ability.

I just tested it in two saved games, one with Elizabeth and one with Augustus.  An embarked land unit in the Elizabeth saved game had six moves, but Augustus' unit only had four.  Both had Astronomy (+1 embarked movement, embarked units can move over ocean) and Steam Power (+1 embarked movement).

Comment: Oh wow, that is such a strong special in that case!